# Run python module within conda env and change working directory using subprocess

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda

I'd like to run a python script that sits within a python module, under an anaconda environment using python's subprocess **(in windows)**.

What i tried was providing full paths for the conda environment, specific python script im trying to run (which sits within some python module) and changing working directory to be the folder which contains the python module, so that all the inner module dependencies will work out:

```
subprocess.Popen("conda run -n <windows_full_path_to_conda_env> python -m <windows_full_path_to_.py_file>", cwd=<windows_full_path_to_dir_containing_.py_file)
```

And i'm receiving the following error

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: it does solve the working directory part, which i did in my code already. but nothing regarding it to run within a conda environment

Comment: Ah sorry, add the parameter `shell=True` if you set the working directory I think you just need the relative path (name of your py file).